# Can't locate package CPAN::Debug for @CPAN::Shell::ISA at

Tags: perl

I'm trying to install a missing module using my script because I can't expect my users to do anything simple as installing a missing module.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use CPAN::Shell;

sub try_load {
  my $mod = shift;    
  eval("use $mod");

  if ($@) {
        #print "\$@ = $@\n";
        return(0);
  } else {
        return(1);
  }
}

my $module = 'URI::Escape';
if (try_load($module)) {
    print "loaded\n";
} else {
    print "not loaded\n";
    CPAN::Shell->install("URI::Escape");
    # system("ppm install ");
}
```

But I always get an error for the above test script :

`Can't locate package CPAN::Debug for @CPAN::Shell::ISA at checkmodule.pl line 3.`

But when I do :

```
my $module = 'CPAN::Debug';
if (try_load($module)) {
    print "loaded\n";
} else {
    print "not loaded\n";
    CPAN::Shell->install("CPAN::Debug");
    # system("ppm install ");
}
```

I get the message `loaded` meaning I do have `CPAN::Debug`   ???.

I can't do : `perl -MCPAN -e shell` because CPAN decided that my version of GCC 4.6.1 is not good enough and wants to install 4.6.3 and that would break a lot of my development environment as well as tools that's installed in my users systems. *[I really wish to force CPAN to use my systems version of MinGW GCC, but I don't know how, but that's for an another time].*

Does anyone know how I could get around this error above in my title?
Thanks!

Comment: It's literally talking about the package, as in the namespace. The problem *isn't* that the module can't be loaded; it's that it *wasn't* loaded. That would seem to indicate you have a messed up CPAN::Shell or CPAN::Debug.

Comment: hey @ikegami , How can I force CPAN to use my system's version of GCC instead of downloading and installing a newer GCC? I don't want to upgrade because some of my tools are compiled using the older version of GCC, and if I upgrade it would mess up a lot of other things. I am trying to make work easier, not harder.

Comment: I don't know.  That is functionality ActiveState adds to their distro.

Answer (score 0):

`CPAN::Shell` is just one component of the `CPAN` module, and isn't intended to be used in isolation

If you just change your `use` statement to `use CPAN` then everything should work for you